# How to detect background color in React

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to detect the background color at one certain point of the page dynamically? I have a website with a fixed header, and the default logo on it is white (default background is black). However, as I scroll down there are sections that have white background, so the logo would have to change colour to black.
Setting it based on scrolling position is not possible, because all sections have different heights and the height is often dependent on the content.

I have found mix-blend-color, but unfortunately its support is pretty bad across browsers. Also tried numerous npm packages, but none of them seem to pick up the background colour.

Is there another way to dynamically change the logo color without getting the background color?

Answer (score 0):

## Answer 1

I never tried this, but I think this might lead to the answer.

You can use [`document.elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint).

This will retrieve the top element at some (x, y) point.

So you can set the `x` and `y` to 1px down the border of your modal ( or some place where you know that will only have element with the background color you want) and get the element.

And check, on a scroll event listener, what is the element at that position and get it's background color.

Is this a good thing to do? Maybe not, but it works and it have good support across browsers.

## Answer 2

> Setting it based on scrolling position is not possible

Of course it's possible!

If your modal is with position absolute, what you can do is get the modal's ref and use `element.getBoundingClientRect()` to get it's position.

Then on each section, you also get the ref (you will have an array of section's ref) in the parent component, which knows the modal's refs and section's ref.

Then, on a scroll event, you use `getBoundingClientRect` on each section element and check if it's inside the modal logo.

To check if it's inside, you can simply use the `top` and `bottom` ( if the scroll is vertical).

This is harder to implement, but I think it's the way to go.